# Adding CORS header files to Spiffy (Scheme/Chicken)

Tags: cors, scheme, chicken-scheme, spiffy

I need to connect a web app to a REST interface made in Scheme/Chicken with Spiffy webserver.

How do you add this header using correct Scheme syntax to the .scm config file (starting Spiffy with CSI -s /www/config.scm)?

The header is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a procedure in `vhost-map`, you can just wrap it in `with-headers`, like so:

```
(vhost-map `((".*" . ,(lambda (cont)
                        (with-headers '((access-control-allow-origin "*"))
                          cont)))))
```

This uses the with-headers procedure which simply adds headers to the response returned by the thunk. See [the Spiffy docs](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/spiffy#procedures-and-macros) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer so people know this is the solution to your question.